# Android Eclipse development Clickable..text pops up

Tags: android, text, colors

I have the following code:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Color Yellow"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#aaaa00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="True"
/>
```

The `android:clickable="True"` was added because I thought it needed to be there (please do correct me if I'm wrong). However, the answer I'm seeking right now is how do I go by making another box (filled with text) pop-up upon clicking the "yellow box".

I would be grateful if someone could provide me with ideas and/or hints regarding how to actually create this scenario.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to have the [autocompletion box](http://android.opensourceror.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/eclipse_suggest_clipped.png) ?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean. But in your Java code dont forget to setOnClickListener if you want to click.

Comment: I,m not understand u r question.

Comment: sorry i will reword better next time

Answer (score 0):

The `android:clickable` element does what you think and what it name tells you. It allows you to receive click events for that view (`TextView` here) to act on these.

To create a popup, you have to assign something to that `TextView` that tells you when it actually gets clicked. That is a `OnClickListener`. You can do that either in code or partially in code and XML. I'll just focus on the code example, but for the record, the XML one is also pretty easy. It involves setting the `android:onClick="myOnClick"` attribute to a certain function name that you like *("myOnClick" here)* and creating a function like `public void myOnClick(View v)` in your activity.

What you have to do in code is

1. Referencing the TextView that you have in your layout
2. Assign the `OnClickListener`
3. Write an action that will be executed once the click gets registered

**First point:** To reference your TextView you have to use `findViewById`

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextviewid);
```

Note that you have to assign a ID to your TextView to identify it. You can set that id via the `android:id` attribute in your XML layout *(e.g. `android:id="@+id/mytextviewid"`)*.

**Second point:** Once you have the reference, use `TextView.setOnClickListener()` to register one.
This usually looks like this:

```
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
            // Add an action here
      }
});
```

**Third point:** All you have to do now is displaying your dialog/message insite the `onClick()` function. There is more than one way to display that, you may use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) or an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog). Check out the links, there are some examples for that.